# Python class variable getting altered by changing instance variable that should just take its value

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, pass-by-reference

I'm stumbling over a weird effect when initializing a Python class. Not sure if I'm overlooking something obvious or not.

First things first, I'm aware that apparently lists passed to classes are passed by reference while integers are passed by value as shown in this example:

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.X = x
    self.Y = y
    self.X += 1
    self.Y.append(1)

x = 0
y = []
Test(x,y)
Test(x,y)
Test(x,y)
print x, y
```

Yielding the result:

```
0 [1, 1, 1]
```

So far so good. Now look at this example:

```
class DataSheet:
  MISSINGKEYS = {u'Item': ["Missing"]}

  def __init__(self,stuff,dataSheet):
    self.dataSheet = dataSheet
    if self.dataSheet.has_key(u'Item'):
      self.dataSheet[u'Item'].append(stuff[u'Item'])
    else:
      self.dataSheet[u'Item'] = self.MISSINGKEYS[u'Item']
```

Calling it like this

```
stuff = {u'Item':['Test']}
ds = {}
DataSheet(stuff,ds)
print ds
DataSheet(stuff,ds)
print ds
DataSheet(stuff,ds)
print ds
```

yields:

```
{u'Item': ['Missing']}
{u'Item': ['Missing', ['Test']]}
{u'Item': ['Missing', ['Test'], ['Test']]}
```

Now lets print `MISSINGKEYS` instead:

```
stuff = {u'Item':['Test']}
ds = {}
DataSheet(stuff,ds)
print DataSheet.MISSINGKEYS
DataSheet(stuff,ds)
print DataSheet.MISSINGKEYS
DataSheet(stuff,ds)
print DataSheet.MISSINGKEYS
```

This yields:

```
{u'Item': ['Missing']}
{u'Item': ['Missing', ['Test']]}
{u'Item': ['Missing', ['Test'], ['Test']]}
```

The exact same output. Why?

`MISSINGKEYS` is a class variable but at no point is it deliberately altered.

In the first call the class goes into this line:

```
self.dataSheet[u'Item'] = self.MISSINGKEYS[u'Item']
```

Which apparently starts it all. Obviously I only want `self.dataSheet[u'Item']` to take the value of `self.MISSINGKEYS[u'Item']`, not to become a reference to it or something like that.

In the following two calls the line

```
self.dataSheet[u'Item'].append(stuff[u'Item'])
```

is called instead and the `append` works on `self.dataSheet[u'Item']` AND on `self.MISSINGKEYS[u'Item']` which it should not.

This leads to the assumption that after the first call both variables now reference the same object.

However although being equal they do not:

```
ds == DataSheet.MISSINGKEYS
Out[170]: True
ds is DataSheet.MISSINGKEYS
Out[171]: False
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on here and how I can avoid it?

EDIT:
I tried this:

```
ds[u'Item'] is DataSheet.MISSINGKEYS[u'Item'] 
Out[172]: True
```

So okay, this one entry in both dictionaries references the same object. How can I just assign the value instead?

Comment: `self.dataSheet[u'Item'] = self.MISSINGKEYS[u'Item']` creates a reference so when you change that you change it everywhere. You would need to create a copy `self.dataSheet[u'Item'] = list(self.MISSINGKEYS[u'Item'])`

Comment: Yeah. This is something about Python I don't understand, 99.9% of all times you never need to consciously create a copy of anything and everything works as if you'd do call-by-value, and then you stumble over something like this suddenly.

Comment: With a mutable object you are creating a reference to something that can be changed, only if the object is immutable will a new object be created if there is a change made so with `i = 12; b = i; i += 12 `  b wil still be 12 as ints are immutable but with a mutable structure the change is done in place so no new object is created. Basically if you want to use a mutable value/obect and don't just want a reference, you need to copy or maybe deepcopy depending on the object.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now.

Comment: No worries, also you should be aware that even if the object itself is immutable, if it contains immutable objects then those objects can still be changed and the immutable object will still be the same object i.e `t = (1,[2]);t=t2;t[1].append(2)`, that is where deepcopy comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
 else:
  self.dataSheet[u'Item'] = self.MISSINGKEYS[u'Item']
```

You are setting `dataShee['Item']` with the list that is the value of `MISSINGKEYS['Item']`. *The same list.* Try

```
 else:
  self.dataSheet[u'Item'] = list(self.MISSINGKEYS[u'Item'])
```

To make a copy.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about what happens in Python function calls in terms of "pass by reference" vs "pass by value" is not generally useful; some people like to use the term "pass by object". Remember, everything in Python is an object, so even when you pass an integer to a function (in C terminology) you're actually passing a pointer to that integer object.

In your first code block you do

```
self.X += 1
```

This *doesn't* modify the current integer object bound to `self.X`. It creates a new integer object with the appropriate value and binds that object to the `self.X` name.

Whereas, with

```
self.Y.append(1)
```

you *are* mutating the current list object that's bound to `self.Y`, which happens to be the list object that was passed to `Test.__init__` as its `y` parameter. This is the same `y` list object in the calling code, so when you modify `self.Y` you are changing that `y` list object in the calling code. OTOH, if you did an assignment like

```
self.Y = ['new stuff']
```

then the name `self.Y` would be bound to the new list, and the old list (which is still bound to `y` in the calling code) would be unaffected.

You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.